# How to see ScrollView's invisible side at Android Studio Preview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

[image]

I want to see that side in the android studio.

Is there any option to see that side?

[image]

and, when LinearLayout reaches that invisible side, suddenly that shadow appears.

how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for disable scrolling stick;

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
 android:scrollbars="none" <!-- line to be added -->
 />
```

Comment: Check my answer if it will really helpful 4 u dude...thnx

Answer (score 3):

try this you can use `android:scrollbars="none"` to disable scrolling stick;

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
  android:scrollbars="none" 
 />
```

**or set it programatically like this**

```
ScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
ScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

**or  to disable blue shadow while scrolling  use this in xml of scrollview**

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

**or use this to change blue shadow while scrolling  use this in xml of scrollview**

```
android:cacheColorHint="#ff00"
```

Comment: Is it impossible to see the invisible side in an android studio?

Comment: didn't get you @DongHyeongJeong

Answer (score 2):

in java add this code

```
myScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
myScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

in xml add following attribute to your ScrollView

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
android:scrollbars="none" <!-- Add this line -->
>
```